# Adding cell values across a row and display result in another cell

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to add all the cell values along a row and put result in another column in Datagridview or listview? If yes, how do I go about that in VB.net please?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straigtforward. Code if the sum column is the last one:

```
    Dim sumRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
    Dim sum As Double = 0

    For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows
        For collumn = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 2
            'check if cell value is a number
            If Double.TryParse(row.Cells(collumn).Value, Nothing) Then
                sum = sum + row.Cells(collumn).Value
            End If
        Next
        row.Cells(sumRowIndex).Value = sum
        sum = 0
    Next
```